# Symmetry in sculpt mode is uneven

Tags: sculpting, coordinates

I am facing problem regarding the symmetry in sculpt mode version 3.3.10.0 . I even brought origin point to the center but still symmetry is uneven.

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe apply the rotation in Object mode? But if it's the problem you'll need to symmetrize your mesh before sculpting again

Comment: Please do not write in all caps.

Comment: moonboots for meshing i think i have to go to edit mode but when i go there blender crashes .

Comment: maybe your mesh is too high-poly? Could you please share your file?

Comment: gordon sir now it is fine will you pls suggest something ?

Comment: ok wait i will share soon

Comment: moonboots how do i share it ? pls help

Comment: Use a platform like workupload for example

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: @moonboots can somebody hack your blender file ?

Comment: @thanos I guess it can happen, to prevent that you can just share a part of the object,or quickly remove the link, actually sometimes it's hard to guess without the file

Comment: @thanos As I said, even if someone did that - don't you have a local copy? Or do you mean someone hacked the file locally on your PC? I for one do not have the skills to do that. And you said in the comments under my answer, it happens with a different file too...

Comment: What can I do now ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to apply the rotation and scale of your object, they should be 0°,0°,0° for the rotation and 1,1,1 for the scale in order to make the symmetrical sculpting work properly. To do this, go into *Object Mode* and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Apply* > *Rotation & Scale*. Or at least the rotation if you want to keep the scale for whatever reason - but on the X axis it has a negative scale which is never a good idea to keep and therefore the body and one leg have their normals flipped (the negative scale is on all objects though). This is also the reason why the sculpt brushes work inverted.

Next time please consider checking if it helps what is suggested in the comments before letting us download a 500+ MB file.

[image: apply transforms]

Comment: Dr Gordon I can't able to use my file . Did you hacked my files ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm at work and cannot answer every second you want me to. How should I hack your file from here? I didn't upload anything... and even if I did, don't you have the file on your own computer?

Comment: I do but every time I open the file not only this file , different model file too my blender get closed automatically.

Comment: Also i can't upload screen recording cause here you can only upload photos . Bad luck otherwise I would have posted it .

Comment: If your file does not open anymore, this has nothing to do with the original post about not sculpting symmetrical and should be asked in a new question. Sounds more like you have a problem with your operating system or resources. Have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: Umm no I just Uninstalled the blender . I will Download different version after that I will see . Actually my laptop is dead so it is on charging .

Comment: What to do now it is hacked

Comment: Did all stuff u said

Comment: Now listen carefully I deleted all my files now downloaded 3.6.2 version. Now it is showing file could not locate I am the cure.blend file . It was old file I deleted all file Now cause it was hacked I will post new question asking for doubts come there sir please

Comment: @thanos This site is for problems with Blender, not hacked files. I don't know what dubious site you uploaded your file to that it got hacked in such a short time? And what is "I am the cure.blend"? The file that was there for download was called "body making.blend". And why a new question? The problem you had was the symmetry. This answer solves the issue. As I said, hacked files are off-topic on this site. I still have the downloaded file on my PC. If you need it, I can upload it for you.

Comment: @thanos I just checked the link where I got your file from. I can still download it there, it is still called "body making.blend", it has the exact same size in bytes and it opens exactly like yesterday. I don't know what kind of chaos you have on your PC, but there is definitely nothing wrong or "hacked" with your file, at least not the one you have uploaded.

Comment: Can I send you a video ?

Comment: How do I delete that link ?

Comment: @thanos How should I know that? I don't use that upload site. And a video about what? A hacked file?

Comment: Yes that same file

Comment: @thanos If your file does not open anymore, what should I look at? This site is for problems working in Blender, if the file does not open you cannot work on it in Blender. And as I said, the file is still there online, everything is okay with it, just download it if the file on your PC is corrupted/broken. And if it still does not open, it might be a bug in Blender or a problem with your hardware etc., **but none of these things are problems suitable for this site and all considered off-topic.**

Comment: Pls give that link then

Comment: Hello, folks, this conversation is getting a bit snarled up. @thanos .. please restrict your questions to problems with the use of Blender, on your own system. Rest assured, no one here has hacked your uploaded file, the link you seek appears to be the one you uploaded it to in the first place?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148364/discussion-on-answer-by-gordon-brinkmann-symmetry-in-sculpt-mode-is-uneven); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: so where to inform about this bug ?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann I posted a new question from there you can get a clue about problem i am facing .